# Openerp override product_id_change function for sale orders

Tags: overriding, odoo, onchange

I need to override the product_id_change function defined in sale.order.line, so it doesn't change the unit_price every time I update the quantity.

I understand I have to use super, but I'm not sure how it all works.

Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straight forward but you need to do a couple of things (assuming OpenERP 7)

1. Create your new module.
2. Create a class that inherits osv.Model
3. Add an _inherit = 'sale.order.line'
4. Implement your new product_id_change method.
5. Install your module and it should work.

A typical pattern is to call super and then process the results.

```
class MyModel(osv.Model):

   _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

   def product_id_change(self, cr, uid, ids, ...):
      res = super(MyModel, self).product_id_change(cr, uid, ids...)

      # do stuff with res.

      return res
```

There is an example of exactly this in the OpenERP sale_margin module in the sale_margin.py file.